# Orbeon Forms on Tomcat - Connect to SQL Server DB via JDBC

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jdbc, orbeon, tomcat8

I am trying to get an Orbeon Forms instance to connect to a SQL Server instance, that I have set up according to the following instructions:

http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html

The DB setup is fine and Orbeon is working perfectly, but errors when it tries to connect to my database (message from the UI is "There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator."):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server ...>
  <Service ...>
    <Engine ...>
      <Host ...>
        <Context
          path="/orbeon"
          docBase="/orbeon"
          reloadable="false"
          override="true"
          allowLinking="true">
          <Resource
            name="jdbc/sqlserver"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            initialSize="3"
            maxActive="10"
            maxIdle="20"
            maxWait="30000"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            poolPreparedStatements="true"
            validationQuery="select 1"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            username="username"
            password="password"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlazureserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=orbeondb;">
          </Resource>
        </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

orbeon.log has no information about a database error and neither does catalina.*.log.

I'm trying to establish whether Orbeon is a viable candidate for a product selection process that I'm involved in currently. It looked promising, but right now it's not standing up too well!

Comment: There should really be something about this in the `orbeon.log`. Could you try setting in up logging per the "Development configuration" as described on http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html#development-configuration, restart Tomcat, and try again? Is there now anything more informative in the `orbeon.log`? Could you also maybe delete the `orbeon.log` before starting Tomcat, reproduce the problem, and put the `orbeon.log` somewhere where we can access it (e.g. you can pasted it on https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me so quickly. OK, I have followed your recommendation and captured a copy of the orbeon.log file - it is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a50a6e87875bdc2127c2

Comment: Looking forward to your feedback...

Comment: In the log, I see the following error: `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. It looks like you were loading a page in your web browser and stopped the loading somehow, or navigated away. I don't see any other error in the log. In your original question, you say "when it tries to connect to my database". What action do you perform exactly before the error shows? Also, in the log, I don't see any attempt to use SQL Server.